# Angular 4: How to create reusable module of base classes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some abstract/base classes, which are inherited by other modules in other applications. These are not services, nor components - just contain some common features that are used by different components - and these components would be used in several different projects.
For example i have a base input class, that is inherited by alphanumeric input class, which is then inherited by an alphabetic and alphanumeric input component having their own separate modules and npm packages ready to be used in future projects.

My plan was to create a base module: a collection of base classes which the component modules could import and extend, but i cannot declare or provide a normal class without @Component/@Pipe/@Directive or @Injectable decorators.

It seems the code would compile if i decorated each base class with @Injectable - but these are not services just code to be inherited later so i dont know if this is the proper/an acceptable approach.

What is the best way to define a such base module with a generic collection of classes to be used in several other independent components? 
Ideally each such component should have its own module and npm package, with a dependency on the base class collection package.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience using `extend` keyword in Angular is a very bad idea because it goes against the concept that the framework tries to represent and can be considered an anti-pattern. You're basically trying to avoid using `Dependency Injection` which is a critical part of this framework.

What you really want to do is create your own module consisting of `Pipes`, `Components` and `Injectables` (also referred as `Services`).

If you want to add functionality to one of the components/services/pipes etc. you should create a service which is going to be injected making testing and maintenance way easier.

e.g. Whenever I'm using `momentjs` I start with creating a service which wraps library's functionality.

Comment: In this context i am trying to create my separate modules with components, where each component shares some basic code/functionality which should be inherited from the base classes.
I would like to avoid having the same code duplicated across each component module, which seems to be really bad practice - probably worse then extending in angular.
Edit: I would be fine with having Injectable() for each base class, just not sure if there would be any unwanted consequences - as these aren't really services or factories.

Comment: In general, you should contain heavier logic in services and make components communicate with them. That's the reason why Dependency Injection exists. Providing more clear context will help me providing you more advice on how you can design your solution.

Comment: I am implementing basic controls, services and wrappers for use in all angular4 projects which we will develop in future.

Comment: The question is what is the best way to achieve having ancestor classes that aren't components or services, just contain the code that otherwise would have to be contained by each class redundantly.
These base classes contain methods, properties and input bindings as well.

Comment: For ex. i have a base input class which is inherited by an alphanumeric control class, which is then inherited by some actual components that handle numbers in a specialized way.
Only the lowest level descendants in the inheritance tree are used in actual projects, the ancestors just contain the common code in an organized manner.

Comment: Right now i defined base classes as Injectables, and provide a new instance of them like a factory. 
Not sure if this is the best approach, i'm not even sure if they need to be part of the DI system at all, or i could just reference them as plain ts classes. My problem with that is that the ancestor classes have Input bindings as well.